# Group all dates that are no more than 90 days apart

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

I have a situation like this:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ObjectA {
     int id;
     LocalDate date;
     int priorityA;
     int priorityB;
}

List<ObjectA> list = List.of(
        new ObjectA(1, LocalDate.parse("2021-09-22"), 2, 1),
        new ObjectA(2, LocalDate.parse("2021-09-22"), 2, 1),
        new ObjectA(3, LocalDate.parse("2022-09-22"), 2, 1),
        new ObjectA(4, LocalDate.parse("2022-10-22"), 2, 1)
);
```

**I have to collapse these objects that are no more than 90 days apart.**

To choose which of the two wins, check:

- first who has the largest "priorityA" attribute, if they are equal then
- check "priorityB", if this is also the same
- check the lesser date and if that is also the same then
- the one with the lesser id.

My implementation is as follows:

```
    List<ObjectA> collapsed = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.groupingBy(
                    ObjectA::getDate,
                    Collectors.maxBy(Comparator
                            .comparing(ObjectA::getPriorityA)
                            .thenComparing(ObjectA::getPriorityB)
                            .thenComparing(ObjectA::getDate)
                            .thenComparing(ObjectA::getId))),
            map -> map.values().stream()
                    .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                    .map(Optional::get)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

But with this implementation I have two problems:

1. I only group objects that have the same date, instead I have to be able to group those that are in the same range of dates, those whose **dates are no more than 90 days apart**.
2. I can't **combine the maxBy** I need for the priorities (priorityA, priorityB) **and the minBy** of data and id.

With proper implementation I should have something like
Example:

```
ObjectA(1, LocalDate.parse("2021-09-22"), 2, 1)
ObjectA(2, LocalDate.parse("2021-09-22"), 2, 1)
ObjectA(3, LocalDate.parse("2022-09-22"), 2, 1)
ObjectA(4, LocalDate.parse("2022-10-22"), 2, 1)
   that became
ObjectA(1, LocalDate.parse("2021-09-22"), 2, 1)
ObjectA(3, LocalDate.parse("2022-09-22"), 2, 1)
```

**Because they have the same priorities and dates in the first pair, so i take the one with smallest id - and in the second pair they have the same priorities but different dates so i take the one with smallest date.**

Could someone with a good heart help me? I have already asked other similar questions here on the forum, but I did not explain myself well enough and the answers however correct were not satisfactory.

EDIT:
"What if you have dates like A=2022-01-01, B=2022-03-01, C=2022-05-01? A and B are within 90 days, and B and C are within 90 days, but A and C are outside of the threshold. Do you group A and B together or B and C together, and why?"

- In this case it will be enough for me to take the first pair, collapsing that the second loses its meaning. The ultimate goal is simply that there are no objects with dates closer than 90 days.

Another example:

- A = 1 priority (01/01/2022)
- B = 9 priority (01/03/2022)
- C = 8 priority (01/05/2022)

A-B take B, B-C take B. So with that 3 I will take only B.

Maybe the solution with stream, collect and Collectors is not the best for this case?

EDIT: That's another way to solve it, how can I improve it?

```
// added a boolean in ObjectA -> "dropped" default false

for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < list.size(); j++) {
                if(list.get(i) == list.get(j) && (list.get(i).dropped || list.get(j).dropped))
                    continue;

                long diff = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(list.get(i).getDate(), list.get(j).getDate());
                if(diff <= daysWindow && diff >= 0 && list.get(i) != list.get(j)) {
                    if (list.get(i).getPriorityA() != list.get(j).getPriorityA()) {
                        if (list.get(i).getPriorityA() > list.get(j).getPriorityA()) {
                            list.get(j).setDropped(true);
                        } else {
                            list.get(i).setDropped(true);
                        }
                    } else if (list.get(i).getPriorityB() != list.get(j).getPriorityB()) {
                        if (list.get(i).getPriorityB() > list.get(j).getPriorityB()) {
                            list.get(j).setDropped(true);
                        } else {
                            list.get(i).setDropped(true);
                        }
                    } else if (list.get(i).getDate().compareTo(list.get(j).getDate()) != 0){
                        if (list.get(i).getDate().compareTo(list.get(j).getDate()) > 0) {
                            list.get(i).setDropped(true);
                        } else {
                            list.get(j).setDropped(true);
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (list.get(i).getId()>list.get(j).getId()) {
                            list.get(i).setDropped(true);
                        } else {
                            list.get(j).setDropped(true);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

 // then i filter for take all objectA with dropped false.
```

Thank you all for the help you can give.

Comment: What if you have dates like A=2022-01-01, B=2022-03-01, C=2022-05-01? A and B are within 90 days, and B and C are within 90 days, but A and C are outside of the threshold. Do you group A and B together or B and C together, and why?

Comment: Good point, in that case I collapse the first two because in fact collapsing those there is no longer the problem with the third. objects are events, I need that they are not close in time and if close to take only those with higher priority. for this I just have to take the first pair. I realize it's a bit complicated, thanks for the interest anyway.

Comment: Every now and then somebody asks similar question as [sql] question, for example this https://stackoverflow.com/q/69296097 today. If you take data from relational db you can consider it. Anyway you need to process sequence using logic where you remember beginning of 90-day window and detect window boundary encountering date beyond 90 day after start of last window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand it correctly it is a two-step sorting problem you have there. First, you need to sort your list by date to be able to group your list of items in a 90-day interval and then re-sort the groups according to your priority requirements.

I would first sort the list by date and remember the date of the first object in an atomic reference. This reference can then be used to form the groups by looking at each iteration to see if the date of the current object is less than 90 days, if so it belongs to the current group otherwise the reference is updated and a new group is formed with the new date as the key. Then you sort the elements of each group and take the first element from each group. To see how to sort groups resulting from the `groupingBy` collector, see this post [sorting-lists-after-groupingby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35872236/sorting-lists-after-groupingby).

Example code, which I have supplemented with additional list elements:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;
import java.util.stream.Collector;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

import static java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.DAYS;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        List<ObjectA> list = List.of(
                new ObjectA(1, LocalDate.parse("2021-09-22"), 2, 1),
                new ObjectA(2, LocalDate.parse("2021-09-22"), 2, 1),

                new ObjectA(3, LocalDate.parse("2022-09-22"), 2, 1),
                new ObjectA(4, LocalDate.parse("2022-10-22"), 2, 1),

                new ObjectA(10, LocalDate.parse("2025-09-22"), 2, 1),
                new ObjectA(20, LocalDate.parse("2025-09-22"), 2, 1),
                new ObjectA(30, LocalDate.parse("2025-09-23"), 2, 1),

                new ObjectA(40, LocalDate.parse("2029-09-22"), 2, 1),
                new ObjectA(13, LocalDate.parse("2029-09-22"), 2, 1),
                new ObjectA(23, LocalDate.parse("2029-09-22"), 2, 1),
                new ObjectA(33, LocalDate.parse("2029-09-22"), 2, 1),
                new ObjectA(4, LocalDate.parse("2029-09-22"), 2, 1)
        );



        // for a better overview single comparators which are used as own variables
        Comparator<ObjectA> byPrioA = Comparator.comparing(ObjectA::getPriorityA, Comparator.reverseOrder());
        Comparator<ObjectA> byPrioB = Comparator.comparing(ObjectA::getPriorityB, Comparator.reverseOrder());
        Comparator<ObjectA> byDate  = Comparator.comparing(ObjectA::getDate);
        Comparator<ObjectA> byId    = Comparator.comparing(ObjectA::getId);

        //first who has the largest "priorityA" attribute, if they are equal then
        //check "priorityB", if this is also the same
        //check the lesser date and if that is also the same then
        //the one with the lesser id.
        Comparator<ObjectA> combined = byPrioA.thenComparing(byPrioB).thenComparing(byDate).thenComparing(byId);

        //sort list by date
        List<ObjectA> sortedByDate = list.stream().sorted(byDate).collect(Collectors.toList());

        //store first date for first group key
        AtomicReference<LocalDate> ar = new AtomicReference<>(sortedByDate.get(0).getDate());

        sortedByDate.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                d -> DAYS.between(ar.get(), d.getDate()) < 90 ? ar.get() : ar.accumulateAndGet(d.getDate(), (u,v) ->v),
                LinkedHashMap::new,
                Collectors.collectingAndThen(toSortedList(combined), l -> l.get(0))))
                .values()
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35872236/sorting-lists-after-groupingby
    static <T> Collector<T,?,List<T>> toSortedList(Comparator<? super T> c) {
        return Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                Collectors.toCollection(()->new TreeSet<>(c)), ArrayList::new);
    }

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @ToString
    public static class ObjectA {
        int id;
        LocalDate date;
        int priorityA;
        int priorityB;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am delighted with this solution, and thank you very much for the detailed explanation. my problem was not knowing the correct use of the AtomicReference as regards the management of dates. An excellent solution is also to divide the Comparators to be able to have the clearest code and about the sorting method. Extraordinary, thank you very much.

Comment: @Ed-Genesis You're welcome. I am glad if I could help you.

Answer (score 1):

Does it work to just pick an arbitrary date within the 90 days and group by that? That seems a simple solution:

```
    List<ObjectA> collapsed = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.groupingBy(
                    x -> LocalDate.ofEpochDay(x.getDate().toEpochDay() % 90),
                    Collectors.maxBy(Comparator
                            .comparing(ObjectA::getPriorityA)
                            .thenComparing(ObjectA::getPriorityB)
                            .thenComparing(ObjectA::getDate)
                            .thenComparing(ObjectA::getId))),
            map -> map.values().stream()
                    .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                    .map(Optional::get)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [StreamEx.collapse](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex):

```
final Comparator<ObjectA> cmp = Comparator.comparing(ObjectA::getPriorityA)
.thenComparing(ObjectA::getPriorityB)
.reversed()
.thenComparing(ObjectA::getDate)
.thenComparing(ObjectA::getId);

List<ObjectA> collapsed = StreamEx.of(list)
    .collapse((a, b) -> ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(a.getDate(), b.getDate()) <= 90,
        (a, b) -> cmp.compare(a, b) <= 0 ? a : b)
    .toList();
```